# Django-filter and Django-tables2 filter with ModelChoice values not filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, django-tables2

I have a filter using ModelChoiceFilter from a DB column called 'semanas' (Weeks) and the values that are stored there at the moment are:

2020-W5
2020-W6

I have the data being displayed in a table (django-tables2), when I select any of these 2 values it does blank like it does not find anything even though I see them displayed in the table.

> filters.py

```
class PagosFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    semana = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Pagos.objects.values_list('semana', flat=True).distinct())

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        fields = ['semana', ]
```

> models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):

    carro = models.ForeignKey(
        Carros, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    pago = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    fecha = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    semana = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    startweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    endweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    renta = models.ForeignKey(
        Renta, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Pagos"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pagos')
```

> tables.py

```
class PagosTable(tables.Table):

    detalles = TemplateColumn(
        '<a class="btn btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url "pagos_edit" record.id %}">Abrir</a>')

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
        fields = ('carro', 'pago', 'fecha', 'semana', 'renta')
        attrs = {"class": "table table-hover table-sm"}
```

> views.py

```
class PagosListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Pagos
    table_class = PagosTable
    template_name = 'AC/payments.html'
    filterset_class = PagosFilter
    paginate_by = 10
```

here is an image displaying filter values

[image]

Here is an image once one of the values of the filter is selected:

[image]

I used to have a value '1' and it worked so I don´t know if the dash in 2020-W06 takes some effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding to the model the string representation.

> models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):

    carro = models.ForeignKey(
        Carros, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    pago = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    fecha = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    semana = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    startweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    endweek = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    renta = models.ForeignKey(
        Renta, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Pagos"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pagos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.semana
```